# How to call a javascript from html using an id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following footer html code

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted"> <a href="about.html">About Us</a> | <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; Copyright of abc
                <span id="yearfooter"> </span>
            </p>
        </div>
</footer>
<script src="scripts/abc.js"></script>
```

and the following for my jscript

```
$(function() {
$('#yearfooter').footer({
    document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
});
```

});

I'm fairly new to javascript. I'm trying to get this script to dynamically get the current year and display that in the footer. But with this, I cant seem to get the year displayed at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `$('#yearfooter').text( (new Date()).getFullYear() )`

Comment: @Michelle your jQuery syntax is incorrect, and using `document.write()` could impact performance.

Comment: Since you are calling `document.write()` after dom ready, it will replace all the contents in the document

Comment: Do what @adeneo mentioned. That'd solve your life.

Comment: I really enjoy seeing people grab someone else solution and offer it as their own answers.

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.write` will overwrite the webpage, so you want something like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted"> <a href="about.html">About Us</a> | <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; Copyright of abc
                <span id="yearfooter"> </span>
            </p>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#yearfooter')` creates a jQuery object that wraps the element with the ID of "yearfooter". Since it's a jQuery object, you can only call jQuery methods (or methods added by jQuery plugins) on it. `footer` is not a jQuery method.

Since you're just trying to update the text inside the "yearfooter" span, you probably want the [jQuery text method](https://api.jquery.com/text/). The syntax for that would just be:

```
$('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this snippet to get the result

```
    function() {
    var date = new Date();  // Get the date object
    var year = date.getFullYear(); // get year from date object 
      // use textcontent to put the text inside the relevant tag using its id
   document.getElementById("yearfooter").textContent = year
    };
```

NOTE: Since you have not tagged this question with jquery so using only javascript

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ahjszk/)

Comment: Note that textContent isn't supported by IE8. However, MS has just dropped support for IE8, so hopefully your website doesn't need to support it anymore, either (but I know that won't be true for everyone). Assuming you don't need to support it, this is probably the best solution, unless you're going to be doing other things with the jQuery object. Why take the performance hit of creating the jQuery object when document.getElementById works just as well in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#yearfooter').html(new Date().getFullYear());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted"> <a href="about.html">About Us</a> | <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p class="text-muted">&copy; Copyright of abc
                <span id="yearfooter"> </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```